# Solving $\int_{-\frac {\pi}{2}}^{\frac {\pi}{2}} \log (1+b \sin x) \sin x\,\mathrm dx$

Tags: calculus

**My attempt:**

[image]

I would prefer a hint, not the solution.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

Let $$\begin{align}&f = \log\left(1 + b\sin x\right)\implies f' = \dfrac{b\cos x}{1 + b\sin x}\\ &g' = \sin x\implies g = -\cos x\end{align}$$

Therefore,

$$\int\log(1 + b\sin x)\sin x\,\mathrm dx = -\cos x\log(1 + b\sin x) + \int\dfrac{b\cos^2 x}{1 + b\sin x}\,\mathrm dx$$

Then, perform [tangent half-angle substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution).

Comment: Ok, I wasn't aware about tangent half-angle substution, let me try it :)

Answer (score 1):

The 2-nd  integral can be solved without tangent half-angle substitution, but by  parts:

$\displaystyle \int \dfrac{b \cos ^2 x}{1 + b \sin x}\,\mathrm dx=\int \cos x \mathrm d \ (\log (1+b \sin x))= \cos x * \log (1+b \sin x)-\frac{1}{b}\int \log (1+b \sin x)d(1+b \sin x)=\cos x * \log (1+b \sin x)-\frac{1}{b}(1+b \sin x)(1-\log (1+b
 \sin x)) $

Comment: Please explain how $\displaystyle \int \frac{b \cos ^2 x}{1+b \sin x} \,\mathrm dx = \int \cos (x)\, \mathrm d( \log (1+ b \sin x) )$ ?

Comment: $\int \dfrac{b \cos ^2 x}{1+b \sin x} dx =/u' =\frac{b \cos  x}{1+b \sin x} dx, u=log (1+ b \sin x)=/ \int \cos (x) d( \log (1+ b \sin x)) $

Comment: But, then how to integrate w.r.t. $\, \mathrm d(\log (1+ b \sin x))$ ?

Comment: I'm not familiar with it ... Do you have a good link on this topic or any source file ?

Comment: You should not integrate it but use integration by parts.

Comment: I would try your method.

Comment: $\displaystyle \int \cos x \  \mathrm d \ (\log (1+b \sin x))= \cos x * \log (1+b \sin x)+\frac{1}{b}\int \log (1+b \sin x) \tan x \ \mathrm d \ (1+b \sin x) $ ?? How did you get $\displaystyle \frac{-1}{b} $ ?